# jquery feature detection - how can I implement this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, detection

I need to prevent IE from recognizing the fadeIn/Out effect in this plugin.  How can I add a line of jquery feature detection code to this:

```
$(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;



$("nav#footer").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.show().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                    });
                    $("nav#footer a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav#footer a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });
    };

});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

I had some code like

```
var FADE_TIME = 500; if(!($.support.opacity)) { FADE_TIME = 0}

$('element').fadeOut(FADE_TIME)
```

Where would I add this in the code? can someone help me get this working for real?please!!

Comment: Honestly. all I need to do is add that support.opacity code to the plugin above it. someone with jquery knowledge please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't figure out why somebody didn't just edit the code and answer the question.
All you needed to do was create a new variable with it's value determined by the $.support.Opacity property then reference that in the fade in/out sections of the code.

```
$(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el,
    // new fadeTime property.
    fadeTime = $.support.opacity ? 500 : 0;



$("nav#footer").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
                $mainContent.show().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(fadeTime, function() {
                    });
                    $("nav#footer a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav#footer a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });
    };

});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to run something if the user isn't using Internet Explorer?

Try this:

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    return false;
} else {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: `$.browser.msie` may not be reliable, consider using feature detection. Refer to documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: no I know I need to use feature detection but how can I add those lines of code I pasted at the top to my plugin??????

Answer (score -1):

I presume you're talking the support for the CSS `opacity` property and not the slightly buggy `-ms-filter` and `filter` which IE8 and below uses. In that case, the best method would be to test for the existence of the property in the `style` object of an element:

```
if('opacity' in document.createElement('div').style) {
    // Do something that requires native opacity support
}
```

(You might want to cache the test element there if you want to test multiple properties)

Comment: Hi Yi - The problem is the black "fuzz" that shows up around transparent images in IE when the pages fade. I just want to prevent IE from fading and just snap from page to page

Comment: @JeffreyJones Have you looked at http://mezzoblue.com/archives/2010/05/20/ie8_still_fa/?